# How to change my pendrive to 64 bits

Tags: usb-modem

I need to boot my pendrive to 64 bits, do you know how I do to change the bits of the pendrive.
I tried to install Windows 10 in the pendrive but I ae my computer have 64 bits and the USB 32 bits.

Comment: A pendrive is not 32 bit or 64 bit. The software you place on it will be either 32 bit or 64 bit. If you have 32 bit software on it and want 64 bit it’s just a case of placing something different on the pendrive. If you want a bootable pendrive find a guide for creating one. There are plenty of written guides on the net and video guides on YouTube

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu: Do you want to install Windows as an installer or as an operating system, (Windows to Go)? Rufus will do both. https://rufus.ie/ if you want to make a Windows installer from Ubuntu Try mkusb-plug https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb